# App restarts when we open the camera or gallery to get photos in react native

Tags: image, camera, react-native, gallery

App restarts when we try to take photo from camera or gallery. I tried to debug the issue or see the logs.
Debug also goes off when we open the camera. so the issue is not after we take the photo but before taking the photo itself. As soon as we open the camera the app would have already lost or destroyed.

Below are the versions used

"react-native": "0.62.2"

"react-native-image-picker": "^2.3.3"

Android version : 9

Device name : Mi a1

and it does not happen every time. If we try for multiple times it works for 2 or 3rd attempt and then starts working.
In the first 2 attempts it will restart for sure.

I have tried all the solutions which are available but still not able to fix this. And it does not happen for all the devices.

Comment: Did you check logcat? What is the crash message there?